# My html code changed

Tags: html, web-hosting

I use the free webhost 000webhost. The host seems to add some tags such as `<tbody>` in the midst of my DOM thereby changing the intended behaviour. Please help. I am new to hosting.

Comment: sorry I meant such as tbody

Comment: Please just update your question instead of making correcting comments.

Answer (score 0):

These tags that you are probably experiencing, is your 'free' webhost inserting ads into your site. As you have noticed, especially with 000webhosting you do get popup ads, as the service is free. So I recommend buying paid hosting, it isn't too expensive http://www.hostgator.com/web-hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're noticing the `<tbody>` tag being inserted, it's likely the browser that's inserting the markup, and not your web host. Tables must have a `<tbody>` tag if they have either `<tfoot>` or `<thead>` sections. Even if you're not using one of those tags, many browsers do automatically insert a `<tbody>`, so if you've got any markup, CSS, or JavaScript that rely on the structure of the table, you should author your tables in full form.

Comment: thnx for that enlightment. I'l have to look up the full significance of these tags

Comment: If this answered your question, I'd appreciate it greatly if you accepted it.